# Убрать индикатор новичка

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, нормы-поведения, индикатор-новичка

Не знаю, будут ли это выносить в настройки или нет, но вот временно скрипт для Tampermonkey, убирающий эти индикаторы:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Contributor indicator cutter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       Suvitruf
// @match        *://*/questions/*
// @match        *://*/review/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';

    var doc             = document;
    var newNode         = doc.createElement ('style');
    newNode.textContent = '.new-contributor-indicator {display: none;}';

    var targ            = doc.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || doc.body || doc.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (newNode);
})();
```

Или для блокировщика правило:

```
##.new-contributor-indicator
```

Comment: Вол-первых, зачем скрипт если есть расширения для css? Во-вторых, какой-то он мутный.

Comment: @Qwertiy изначальная версия была проще. Но на странице ревью контент подгружается не сразу, поэтому пришлось сделать таким образом.

Comment: Суть я думаю не в скриптах, а в том что это абсолютно не нужная штука на сайте. Может со временем она перестанет напрягать, как постоянных пользователей так и новичков включительно, но для этого нужно немного времени. Или накопиться много негатива и это уберут или обратный вариант.

Comment: А чем он мешает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov своим существованием.

Comment: Подозреваю, с вот этим вот бинайсом™ индикатор наоборот будут делать ещё заметнее :)

Comment: Сделал себе подобное, только вырезал все ноды, вместо скрытия онных.

Answer (score 9):

Или же можно использовать юзерстиль:

```
/* ==UserStyle==
@name           Stackoverflow new contributor indicator remover
@namespace      github.com/openstyles/stylus
@version        1.0.0
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("*.stackoverflow.com") {
    .new-contributor-indicator {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: А как это включить в свой браузер?

Comment: @avp, с помощью расширения, например tampermonkey. Для CSS у меня стоит Stylebot: создаете стиль для URL `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/` и в его тело помещаете `.new-contributor-indicator { display: none; }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо! Но без детальной инструкции для FF это для меня все равно "китайская грамота"

Comment: @avp, на FF установил дополнение Stylish и вот так добавил стиль: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C44me.gif

Comment: @АндрейNOP срочно удаляйте его, Stylish - это теперь шпионское ПО...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так что надо сделать?

Comment: @avp поставить stylus, а дальше то же самое

Comment: `stylus`  это дополнение, которое надо искать через браузер (там где ставятся дополнения) или нечто внешнее?

Comment: @avp откуда я знаю как в вашем FF ставятся дополнения?

Comment: @avp, да, меню - дополнения, в поисковую строку вбиваете и ставите. Вот прямая ссылка: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/styl-us/?src=search

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ок, вообще я не пользуюсь FF. Хотя, может это уже не акутально? Вернули ведь его в каталог. Разработчики, вроде, обещали выпилить из него шпионские модули, хотя я не сильно слежу за этими новостями